# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable error in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that checks if any digit in the integer you entered is an odd number and if it is it then doubles the number. And then if the number is more than or equal to 10 it takes away 9 But I'm getting this error and I don't know why:
Here's the error:

```
CSE\Check it out.py", line 24, in <module>
    d1 = check(card_no[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's my code:

```
def reverse_int(n):
  return int(str(n)[::-1])

  def check(n):
  if(n == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9):
  n = n*2
  else:
  return n
  if(n >= 10):
  n = n-9
  return n
  else:
  return n

  card_no = str(input("Please enter your card number > > "))
  no_len = len(card_no)

  if(no_len == 8):
  check_digit = card_no[7]
  card_no = card_no[0:7]
  card_no = reverse_int(card_no)
  d1 = check(card_no[0])
  d2 = check(card_no[1])
  d3 = check(card_no[2])
  d4 = check(card_no[3])
  d5 = check(card_no[4])
  d6 = check(card_no[5])
  d7 = check(card_no[6])
```

Comment: Clearly as the error says, `card_no` is an `int`. What do you expect `card_no[0]` to return? It is equivalent to `7[0]`.

Comment: `card_no = reverse_int(card_no)` and `reverse_int` returns an `int`, seems pretty obvious what the issue is my friend.

Comment: also about `if(n == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9):` you will want to look at [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementation of Luhn Formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079439/implementation-of-luhn-formula)

Comment: For what it's worth, I fail to see the purpose of converting back and forth between str and int.